# Include Subtotal Column Name On Each Of the Subtotal Rows in BI-Publisher using guided format

Tags: bi-publisher

I have a simple data where I am making a matrix table and include subtotals for Acct, Div Bu and Dept as shown in the below sample.
[image]

I am using the guided format to make the report. I want to include each of the Acct, Div Bu and Dept Name for the Subtotal Rows.

The subtotal rows should contain Total for 2320-100, Total for 5040, Total for 0000 instead of Total for Dept, Total for Div Bu and Total for Acct.